# How to change the system language from Universal Win 10 app using C#?

Tags: c#, windows-10-universal

I want to  change the system language of a Universal Win 10 app using C# code.

I tried this code:

```
var culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-be");

Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = culture.Name;

Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceContext.GetForCurrentView().Reset();
Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceContext.GetForViewIndependentUse().Reset();
```

But this did not work because I want to change the client language, not my app language.

Comment: Why would an app ever do such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, [ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh972398) is used to get or set an override for the app's preferred language.

The windows store apps run in sandbox. You cannot set system language directly by coding. It requires users to open "Settings-Time&Language" to set themself.

But you can use [Launch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-settings-app) to open the settings page.

```
bool result = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-settings:regionlanguage"));
```